# Error on creating record in Ember with hasMany

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I try to create a record which has a oneToMany relationship like this :

`App.Models.Esnode = DS.Model.extend({
     nodeUrl: DS.attr('string'),
     nodeState: DS.attr('string'),
     indices: DS.hasMany(App.Models.Index)
});`

And

```
App.Models.Index = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

In the function model of the ApplicationRoute, I do this :

```
this.store.createRecord(App.Models.Esnode, {nodeUrl: "http://192.168.1.13:9200"});
```

Which gives the error :

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'links' of null
```

in the Ember data code at line 5938, in the method reloadHasManys :

```
if (this._data.links && this._data.links[name]) { return; }
```

And indeed this._data is undefined but should not be as the data ha not yet been initialized at this point in the createRecord method. I checked my mappings, tried different things but nothing worked. I didn't find anything on this problem. Did I do something wrong.

I am on the 1.5.1 of Ember and 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88 of Ember data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your model in the App namespace and reference any relationships by their name, not the actual variable, like this:

```
App.Esnode = DS.Model.extend({ 
    nodeUrl: DS.attr('string'), 
    nodeState: DS.attr('string'), 
    indices: DS.hasMany('index') 
});
```

And then when you create a record, you pass in the string name of the type of record you're creating, like this:

```
this.store.createRecord('esnode',{
     nodeUrl: "http://192.168.1.13:9200"
});
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I found why it doesn't work. In fact I had overridden the init function in the esnode object. The function wasn't doing anything. I removed it and it works. What's weird is that if I had some treatment in the init method, it doesn't work. It seems that my init function doesn't call the super init method automatically. Anyway, thanks :)